# Installing JDK and setting JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, java-home

1. What exactly is the purpose of JDK - running java programs or developing?
2. There seems to be too many packages that include java and jdk/sdk in their title. Which one should I install if I want to develop Java applications?
3. Who uses JAVA_HOME and what should I set it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JDK is development environment. JVM is runtime environment.
2. You should download java installer from oracle web site or install it from repositiry manager
3. `JAVA_HOME` system variable usually is required for enterprice java software (application servers, DBs, development tools and so on). You should set `JAVA_HOME` variable to root directory of JDK or JVM(setting it to JDK always works, but maybe some software will run as expected with `JAVA_HOME` pointing to JRE). If you set `JAVA_HOME` right then `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` command should pring version of java.

Comment: JVM is the virtual machine. I think what you meant was JRE.

Answer (score 2):

**JRE** means Java Runtime Environment. Most Java Software only needs a **JRE** to run.

**JDK** means Java Development Kit. A **JDK** allways includes a **JRE**. If you develop you most certainly allways use the **JDK**, since it contains source and docs of java's own Classes.

Also there is software (usually software for development) that uses tools of the **JDK** to run, e.g. this software needs the **JDK** as runtime environment (for example: ant).

**JVM** means Java Virtual Machine and is the program that runs your java program no matter if in **JRE** or **JDK**.

`JAVA_HOME` is the path to the **JDK**

`JRE_HOME` is the path to the **JRE**

Answer (score 1):

1. **JDK** - Java Development Kit (in contrast to **JRE** - Java Runtime Environment).
2. If you don't know which version of Java you need, just get the latest (currently **Java Platform (JDK) 7u5**). Unless you already have a development tool, you might want the Netbeans bundle instead.
3. **JAVA_HOME** is used by some software that depends on Java - ant, which is a build tool, is one that comes to mind. It should be set to the directory which contains the `bin` directory, which in turn contains the java executables.